# Sraping with Beautifulsoup-Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

[image]I am trying to scrape some data from the link: http://www.airlinequality.com/airline-reviews/vietjetair/?sortby=post_date%3ADesc&pagesize=100

For example I am trying with BeautifulSoup to extract the name of each reviewer but it doesn't work. I have tried before to use BeautifulSoup with other website and it worked perfectly! I don't know what is happening. Can you help me. The code is the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import urllib.request


file1 = open(os.path.expanduser(r"~/Desktop/Skytrax Reviews1.csv"), "wb")

file1.write(b"Reviewer" + b"\n")

WebSites = ["http://www.airlinequality.com/airline-reviews/vietjetair/?sortby=post_date%3ADesc&pagesize=100"]


# looping through each site until it hits a break. I will create a loop. It is not ready yet
for theurl in WebSites:
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(theurl)
    print(thepage)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage,'lxml')
    print(soup)    #<-------This is the main problem 

#Maybe it is not correct too but the main problem is at the above lines
    for Reviewer in soup.findAll(attrs={"class": "text_sub_header userStatusWrapper"}).text:
        print(Reviewer)

        Record1 = Reviewer
        file1.write(bytes(Record1, encoding="ascii", errors='ignore') + b"\n")


file1.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The site isn't returning what you see on the browser, try:

```
wget -qO- http://www.airlinequality.com/airline-reviews/vietjetair/?sortby=post_date%3ADesc&pagesize=100
```

or try changing the user agent of the request.

Comment: @Rusa_x Thank you for your answer. I am new in python I use the same link as yours.

Answer (score 0):

If you open that website with Chrome `Network Tools` or `Firebug` you'll noticed that it uses `cookies` to validate the requests.

You can emulate the cookies by creating a `dict` with Python and send them with your request.

In my example I'm using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/). Also, you shouldn't put `.text` in your loop, it'll give you an error.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

cookies = {
'PHPSESSID':'1gd0sknluds2uvumsglth523g5',
'visid_incap_965359':'UGNtvJR1TAmP1y+/M85QuJ1s3lgAAAAAQUIPAAAAAAB5IOYuRCw/9mMOpTnRDCJ6',
'incap_ses_315_965359':'PRZ8WIgqnhyeicz5PxxfBLFs3lgAAAAAYWoblc6exwqhEeGRPqgA5Q=='
}

response = requests.get('http://www.airlinequality.com/airline-
reviews/vietjetair/?sortby=post_date%3ADesc&pagesize=100', cookies=cookies)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
for Reviewer in soup.findAll(attrs={"class": "text_sub_header userStatusWrapper"}):
    print(Reviewer.get_text(strip=True))
```

[image: Cookies]

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!! But form the soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser") I take the same answer <html style="height:100%"><head><meta content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW" name="ROBOTS"><meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection"><meta content="initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport"><meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/></meta></meta></meta></head><body....

Comment: Use different cookie values - go to network tools and find yours to test;

Comment: @Zrop. I Change the cookies but the code print(Reviewer.get_text(strip=True)) doesn't print anything

Comment: I've attached an image. Are you using that values?

Comment: @ Zroq I've attached an image in order to see the values. Thank you!